# How insert text into word and convert it into pdf

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, ms-word

| First Name | Last Name | File Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | Lee |  |
| Jason | Hulce |  |
| Ibrahim | Muhammad |  |

I am trying to make an E-certificate for all the user that are listed in the table. I have imported the data into my database(phpmyadmin).

I have design a Microsoft Word certificate, just wondering is it possible to insert the name of the participant in the file and convert it into a pdf? There are around 500 participants and if I am to update one by one in word it is time consuming.

I am trying to do it in PHP and JS. Do you guys have any other idea on how to make this work?

Comment: create a dynamic html and convert it to pdf using [`mpdf`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/writehtml.html#examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it using class named **ZipArchive**.

I am adding a sample code. You can change it according to your needs.

```
<?php
$template_file_name = 'certificate.docx';
$rand_no = rand(111111, 999999);
$fileName = $rand_no . ".docx";
$folder   = "results";
$full_path = $folder . '/' . $fileName;
try
{
    if (!file_exists($folder))
    {
        mkdir($folder);
    }
    //Copy the Template file to the Result Directory
    copy($template_file_name, $full_path);
    // add calss Zip Archive
    $zip_val = new ZipArchive;
    //Docx file is nothing but a zip file. Open this Zip File
    if($zip_val->open($full_path) == true)
    {
        // In the Open XML Wordprocessing format content is stored.
        // In the document.xml file located in the word directory.
        $key_file_name = 'word/document.xml';
        $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);
        $timestamp = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');
        // this data Replace the placeholders with actual values
        $message = str_replace("full_name",      "John Doe",       $message);
        $message = str_replace("email_address",  "abc@email.com",  $message);
        //Replace the content with the new content created above.
        $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
        $zip_val->close();
    }
}
catch (Exception $exc) 
{
    $error_message =  "Error creating the Word Document";
    var_dump($exc);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library, you can create and word document and pdf. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/